# C# ObservableCollection OnCollectionChanged not firing when item changes

Tags: c#, wpf, collections, observablecollection

From the MSDN about OnCollectionChanged: "Occurs when an item is added, removed, changed, moved, or the entire list is refreshed."

I'm changing a property attached to an obj that resides in my collection, but OnCollectionChanged isn't fired. I am implementing iNotifyPropertyChanged on the obj class.

```
public class ObservableBatchCollection : ObservableCollection<BatchData>
    {
        protected override void OnCollectionChanged(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
            {
                foreach (BatchData item in e.NewItems)
                {

                }
            }
            base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
        }

        public ObservableBatchCollection(IEnumerable<BatchData> items)
            : base(items)
        {

        }
}
```

To me, that reads that when an item in the collection is changed, such as a property of the object, that this event should fire. It's not, however. I want to be able to know when an item in my custom collection changes so I can perform a calculation on it, if needed.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ObservableCollection<T>` raises events only when the *collection itself changes*. An item contained in the collection that has its internal state mutated has not altered the structure of the collection, and `ObservableCollection<T>` will not report it.

One option is to subclass `ObservableCollection<T>` and subscribe to each item's `OnPropertyChanged` event when it is added. In that handler, you can raise either a custom event, or fall back to the collection's own `PropertyChanged` event. Note that if you do go this route, you should add a generic constraint so that `T : INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Yup, by "changed" they mean doing `collection[i] = newItem;`, not changing the old item.

Comment: Oh. The documentation is a bit unclear, to me. "...when an item is ...changed", to me, means 'when an item is changed'. Hehe. Thanks all.

Comment: You're correct - it's unclear because it's worded incorrectly. "Occurs when an item is added, removed, *changed*, moved, or when the entire list is refreshed" - the placement of commas indicates that you should read it as: "when an item is added, (when an item is) removed, (when an item is) changed, (when an item is) moved, or when the entire list is refreshed".