# How to be notified when an item of an ObservableCollection is replaced

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I want to add an event handler to an observable collection that will be triggered each time items are added, removed, or updated in it.

The CollectionChanged event is raised when items are added or removed but is not raised when items are replaced e.g. with something like this

```
obsList[5] = MyUpdatedCustomObject;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099050/c-sharp-observablecollection-oncollectionchanged-not-firing-when-item-changes

Comment: Its not a dublicate there user referred to changing just a property of MyUpdatedCustomObject while what i am asking here is a bit different

Comment: how do you listen to the ObservableCollections changed event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought, you can't do this, the indexer:

```
public T this[int index] { get; set; }
```

is inherited from `Collection<T>` class, this indexer is not virtual to change its behavior!

But actually, when I tested on a very tiny application, the event will fire in your case, you have something wrong, please supply some extra code!

Answer (score -3):

```
private ObsersvableCollection<Type> _MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<Type>();

_MyCollection.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(_MyCollection_CollectionChanged);

protected void _MyCollection_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch(e.Action)
    {
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
            //use e.NewItems to get items added.     
        break;
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
            //use e.OldItems to get items removed.
        break;

    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't cover OP's need to be notified when an item is *updated*.

Comment: You don't need the empty delegatehandler - `_MyCollection.CollectionChanged += _MyCollection_CollectionChanged;` is sufficient